# Store several form values in one cookie

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript novice and would appreciate a little advice.

I found online a snippet that allows to save form input values in separate cookies:

```
function storeValues(form)  
  {
    setCookie("field1", form.field1.value);
    setCookie("field2", form.field2.value);
    setCookie("field3", form.field3.value);
    setCookie("field4", form.field4.value);
    return true;
  }
```

How should this be modified to store values from several inputs in a single cookie?

Comment: do you already know the order of the inputs?

Comment: Yes, @ebram – could you tell me if it has to be unique for each specific order of inputs, or there is a generic way to do that, which could be adapted to any form?

Comment: Depending on what method you use, the order might matter. If you use JSON, then the cookie will be a little bit bigger, but the order won't matter. If you use a character delimited method then the order will matter, but the cookie will be smaller. If you use a character delimited method, be careful that the character you use to delimit isn't in any of the strings you are storing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the values. Be sure to use a separation format that allows you to retrieve the values later:

```
setCookie( 'fieldname', form.field1.value + ',' + form.field2.value + ','... );
```

Comment: Be careful that form.field1.value doesn't contain any commas or your code might break. For example, if you are asking people what their favorite drink is, and they answer "tea, or maybe coffee", then that would mess up your cookie

Comment: @KevinJohnson That is a useful point. This approach is quick and dirty. For better data protection consider encapsulating the data perhaps in the manner [described](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303147/store-several-form-values-in-one-cookie/17303230?noredirect=1#comment25092328_17303230#answer-17303233) by Matthew Graves or [Kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303147/store-several-form-values-in-one-cookie/17303230?noredirect=1#answer-17303314).

Answer (score 4):

You could store the values as json:

```
function storeValues(form)  
{  
    setCookie("form", JSON.stringify({field1:form.field1.value,
                       field2:form.field2.value,
                       field3:form.field3.value,
                       field4:form.field4.value});
    return true;
}
```

and then to access it:

```
JSON.parse(getCookie("form"));
```

Comment: Thank you, @Matthew. Could you please tell me, what is the advantage of the method you're suggesting, when compared to the solution proposed by George Cummins?

Comment: Using JSON will let you do what you're looking to do without writing a parser for splitting the data on commas, or spaces, or some other delimiter as the standard JSON library will do both the encoding and decoding. 

It will also allow you to extend the code more easily.

JSON notation is also sort of a standard data exchange format.

Furthermore the JSON.parse operation will give you a javascript object with properties that are nicely accesible like obj.field1, obj.field2, etc. rather than doing it with an array or something.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so thoroughly, @Matthew.

Answer (score 2):

Since a cookie is just Key --> Value (string), you would have to place your multiple inputs into one string and then store that.

If you aren't sure of the format of what you want to save, you could write your values into JSON, and save that. Something like...

```
{
   "field1": form.field1.value,
   "field2": form.field2.value,
   "field3": form.field3.value,
   "field4": form.field4.value,
}
```

Or if you already have the data arranged in a Javascript structure that is easy to access, just pass that into `JSON.stringify()`, and save the returned string into the cookie.

Or if you aready know the format, and know that a certain character won't be used in the values (but you probably don't because you're using form inputs), you could use some sort of character delimited string. Something like... (comma used as delimiter in example)

```
string = form.field1.value + "," + form.field2.value + "," + form.field3.value + "," + form.field4.value + ",";
```

Once you have the string, save that into the cookie with what you know.